# ajaxfileupload issues Google Chrome

Tags: jquery

I'm working in a project and I've use ajaxfileupload.js as file uploader. This plugins used jQuery and my project jquery version is 1.6.4

It's working great in Mozilla/IE/Opera. But unfortunately It's not working in Google Chrome.
When I've try to upload a file then in debugger I found an error.

**Error Message:**
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'handleError'

I'd tried on it more than 4 hours and I'd not got any solutions.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the latest version of jquery.form.js
I got it from here: http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js
and it solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're including the:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax_upload.js"></script>
```

If it's finding 'no method' in the script file, it's probably because it's not being referenced on the site properly.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the try-catch, leaving what's inside try {...} block from the fileuploader.js
Also, be sure to do a 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload' or at least ctrl+F5, because chrome often uses the cached version of the file, not the one with latest changes.